# Add bitbucket artifact as prebuilt to AOSP manifest

Tags: android-source, bitbucket-pipelines, repo, android.mk

Assuming we have a JAR file that is generated with BitBucket Pipelines and is accessible via a URL (ie BB downloads)

What would be the best way to dynamically (based on branch) add the correct jar file as a prebuilt binary to AOSP ?

Can Android.mk download the file given the URL (which may include the version)?

In short I want to add various **prebuilt** APKs and JARs to AOSP but follow a versioning system per branch. I do not want to download and build from source code and as such the source code gif shouldn’t be included. I also do not want the binary to be in a git repo as advised everywhere.

From what I’ve been reading the repo manifest always points to git repos.

I recognize a git repo may be needed to setup Android.mk to start with but then want to pull the binary from non-git url so that I don’t store binary releases in my git repository and furthermore allowing me to use BB pipelines and downloads for binary storage.

If I setup a new repo to hold only the Android.mk file changes (which I’m hopping to update with pipelines when a new version is available) how do I get repo and AOSP to fetch the correct file to be added as a prebuilt?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK AOSP build downloads nothing while building. Everything (all the sources and prebuilt stuff) is downloaded while performing `repo sync`. And there is some rationale behind it...

So I'm afraid you have to keep those libraries in some git repo, probably the one that will also contain `Android.mk` (or `Android.bp`) that will instruct build what to do with those.